# Htaccess, 301 redirect with exception

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've a WP site and I changed the permalinks, but to keep google indexed urls working I tried to set 301 redirect rules. That works but I now have the issue that the category pagination doesn't work anymore. So I need to add a exception to the condition, but how do I do that?

Current rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^category/blog/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But I need it to be ignored when $1 contains page/ so urls like category/blog/page/2 can pass. 
How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond $1 !page [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/blog/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: +1 but for my education, would this have worked without the RewriteCond? `RewriteRule ^category/blog/((?!page$).*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: Thanks @zx81, Yes absolutely it will work with that regex as well.

Comment: Ha, great, I understood something. :) Thanks, learning a lot from your answers! :)